# Dreamweaver: While executing inspectSelection in asp_command.htm, a JavaScript error occurred

Tags: vbscript, dreamweaver, ado

I was getting an error that was driving me crazy when putting ado commands on an AJAX page.

Here is the error:

> Dreamweaver While executing inspectSelection in asp_command.htm, a
>   JavaScript error occurred.

Here is some sample code that produces the error:

```
dim rsResearchSubmit_cmd
set rsResearchSubmit_cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
rsResearchSubmit_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_VETR_STRING
rsResearchSubmit_cmd.CommandText = "dbo.usp_SubmitDisagreeResearch"
rsResearchSubmit_cmd.CommandType = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I found that the problem is in the "set" line. DreamWeaver is expecting a space after Server.CreateObject and before the ("ADODB.Command")

So the line that resolves the error is:

```
set rsResearchSubmit_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
```

I hope this helps someone out there!